# How to fix AttributError: module "x" has no attribute

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyinstaller, converters

I'm trying to convert my project into exe. This is tkinter gui-type project. Everything works fine in environment, but when I convert it to exe I do encounter one problem. Gui displayes, but the main class is not working. I receive:

> AttributeError: module 'email' has no attribute 'Send_email'

The below code works pefectly from visual studio, but stops when converted to exe. Appreciate for any help.

```
import email  ##my .py file with class
main_class = email.Send_email() ## getting Send_email class
main_class.mechanism_bot(user,issue,body) ## getting the function from the class
```

Comment: How are you converting it?

Comment: @JammyDodger pyinstaller with console log, "pyinstaller main.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `email` is a standard module name in Python. Have you tried renaming your module to something else?

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#module-email

Comment: Will do it, still have to wait 2 mins :) Thanks again ! such an obvious thing and was a nightmare since yeterday !

Comment: Don't feel too bad -- I know I've done the same thing more than once. :)